# Highchart draggable point - watch changes from component

Tags: angular, highcharts

Is it somehow possible to track or watch changes in draggable point highchart. I need to call set function from component every time some value changed.

[Code Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-n9ufm)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the demo shared in the below API link is a good start to accomplish your requirement.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.point.events.dragStart

Comment: Yeah I was able to use drop event in highchart itself but I need to catch this something changed event in component which only initialized this highchart.

Comment: May I see a sample demo to know how your component looks like?